# Spring Boot @JmsListener not consuming

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I am able to post message into ActiveMQ, but my `@JmsListener` is not consuming the messages. Below is my code.

**JmsConfig.java**

```java
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListener;
import org.springframework.jms.config.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageType;

import com.sc.cib.api.dto.model.user.UserDto;

@Configurable
@EnableJms
public class JmsConfig {
    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> myFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                            DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
      DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
      configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
      return factory;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter() {
      MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
      converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
      converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
      return converter;
    }

    @JmsListener(destination = "user.inbound")
    public void receiveMessage(UserDto usr) {
      System.out.println("Received <" + usr + ">");
    }
}
```

Here's a screenshot from the ActiveMQ Admin Console showing that there are messages in the queue `user.inbound` but no consumers.

[image]

I have configured broker details in `application.properties`. Below are the details:

```
spring.activemq.broker-url=tcp://localhost:61616
spring.activemq.user=admin
spring.activemq.password=admin
```

Comment: Yes. Have added the Console screen shot to the original message.

Comment: I don't see where you're configuring your `@JmsListener` to connect to the remote ActiveMQ instance. Where is the broker listening?

Comment: have update the activemq configuration details

Answer (score 1):

You have used a non-standard name for the container factory bean; you need to set the `containerFactory` property or change the bean name to `jmsListenerContainerFactory` to override Boot's default factory.